# Sort ascending list by price

Tags: java

I have this function. This function sort ascending list by price

```
public void f3(List<Fan> list) {
    for (Fan fan : list) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Fan>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Fan o1, Fan o2) {
                if (o1.getPrice() > o2.getPrice()) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (o1.getPrice() < o2.getPrice()) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

when I call to this function. It was an error

OUTPUT:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
at MyFan.f3(MyFan.java:41)
at Main.main(Main.java:78)
```

Comment: Why would you sort a list in a loop? Remove the outer loop or move the sorting outside of it and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate the list in order to make the sort call work.  Just call `Collections.sort()` directly:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Fan>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Fan o1, Fan o2) {
        if (o1.getPrice() > o2.getPrice()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o1.getPrice() < o2.getPrice()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that in Java 8 you may take advantage of the much less verbose lambda way of doing this:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Fan::getPrice));
```